# Как можно привязать OnMouseDown или подобную ей к коллайдеру объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не бейте сильно, язык для меня новый.
В Unity2d реализовано движение объекта курсором мышки через OnMouseDown, и при первом клике объект должна вызваться функция с задержкой, которая ждет 3 секунды и потом выводит ответ в консоль. Все вроде так, вот только как можно привязать клик к конкретному объекту, ибо при клике срабатывают разные функции с разными значениями в консоль всех объектов, при этом одновременно? Или воспользоваться другой функцией. Пролистал кучу форумов, и документацию прочел, но, может быть, я слепой, но ответа там не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Повесьте скрипт на нужный объект, и в нем обрабатывайте OnMouseDown(). Я не вижу вашего кода, и если там что-то напутано, то можете прикрутить проверку на имя объекта в этом событии на крайний случай. OnMouseDown() и так обрабатывает нажатие на коллайдер объекта.